# CheckBox com PHP

Tags: php

O site possui 3 *checkbox*, mas irei implementar muito mais.
O problema é que meu código não está muito legal, pois preciso calcular o valor total

Código está assim:

```
$hena = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "hena", FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
$simples = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "simples", FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
$maquiagem = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "maquiagem", FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);

$valorHena = 20; // Valor da Hena
$valorSimples = 15; // Valor da Simples
$valorMaquiagemIndividual = 100; // Valor da maquiagem individual

if (isset($hena) && !isset($simples) && !isset($maquiagem)) {
        $dado->setResultado($valorHena);
    }elseif (isset($simples) && !isset($hena) && !isset($maquiagem)) {
        $dado->setResultado($valorSimples);
    }elseif (isset($maquiagem) && !isset($hena) && !isset($simples)) {
        $dado->setResultado($valorMaquiagemIndividual);
    }elseif (isset($hena) && isset($simples) && !isset($maquiagem)) {
        $resultado = $valorHena + $valorSimples;
        $dado->setResultado($resultado);
    }elseif (isset($hena) && isset($maquiagem) && !isset($simples)) {
        $resultado = $valorHena + $valorMaquiagemIndividual;
        $dado->setResultado($resultado);
    }elseif (isset($maquiagem) && isset($simples) && !isset($hena)) {
        $resultado = $valorMaquiagemIndividual + $valorSimples;
        $dado->setResultado($resultado);
    }elseif (isset($maquiagem) && isset($simples) && isset($hena)) {
        $resultado = $valorHena + $valorSimples + $valorMaquiagemIndividual;
        $dado->setResultado($resultado);
    }
```

Como vocês podem ver está bastante confuso, queria dar uma melhorada e tentei de tudo alguém poderia dar uma dica ?

Comment: Do jeito que estamos vendo não está confuso, está impossível de entender, kkkk, mas arrumando esse código não vejo o porque querer melhorar. Pergunto: está funcionando bem? Se está então está bom!

Comment: kkk sim ele funciona o porém desse código é que vou ter que incrementar mais de 10 elseif.

Comment: tem o switch case que tb vai dar o mesmo trabalhão

Comment: tem como vc clicar em editar na minha resposta, copia e cola na sua pergunta

Comment: Eu pensei também no switch Porém na parte do case precisaria passar 2 informações ao mesmo tempo e não sei fazer :/

Comment: é rapaz, com mais 10 inputs vai dar um trabalhao mesmo esse if else. To pensando aqui numa forma de colocar num array

Comment: Você tem uma noção de como faria isso?

Comment: Olá, isso parece revisão de código.

Comment: Eu sei você está tentando ajudar relaxa. eu vou tentar dar um jeito se eu conseguir um código mais bonito kk eu posto aqui assim outras pessoas veem também

Comment: Leo achei uma solução mas não sei se é boa ou ruim mas já da uma boa limpada no código. É usar o ternário                                 
$resultado = (isset($hena))? $resultado + $valorHena : $resultado;
$resultado = (isset($simples))? $resultado + $valorSimples : $resultado;
 $resultado = (isset($maquiagem))? $resultado + $valorMaquiagemIndividual : $resultado;

Comment: Rapaz, acordei tarde e já botaram uma resposta utilizando array, kkk, Quem vai ao mar perde o lugar e quem vai ao vento perde o assento. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Irei demonstrar duas maneiras de melhorar isto, uma mais fácil de entender (utilizando loops explícitos) e outra utilizando funções de manipulação de array, no final ambos atingem o mesmo objetivo. Ambos permitem adicionar e remover itens sem a necessidade de alterar ou adicionar comparadores/condições ao código, apenas adicionando um item na *array*.

---

Primeiro **em ambos os casos** defina um array com os valores:

```
$valoresProdutos = [

    'Hena' => 20,
    'Simples' => 15,
    'MaquiagemIndividual' => 100

];
```

Depois precisará somar os valores:

```
/*1*/ $produtosEscolhidos = $_POST;

/*2*/ $valoresEscolhidos = array_intersect_key($valoresProdutos, $produtosEscolhidos);

/*3*/ $valoresSomados = array_sum($valoresEscolhidos);

/*4*/ echo $valoresSomados;
```

[TESTE ISTO AQUI.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8266f93cc421c568d54affbb1179cbcae435129c)

*Se quiser "tudo em uma linha":*

```
echo $valoresSomados = array_sum(array_intersect_key($valoresProdutos, $_POST));
```

**Traduzindo o que é feito:**

1. O `$produtosEscolhidos` possui todos as informações do [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php), *em array*, dessa forma se o corpo do `POST` for `Hena=Qualquer_Coisa&Simples=ABC` então a array será `array( "Hena" => "Qualquer_Coisa", "Simples" => "ABC" )`.

> Você poderia também utilizar `$produtosEscolhidos = array_flip(array_keys($_POST))` para deixar claro que o que interessa seria a chave e não os valores, o [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php) pega as chaves do `POST`, isto irá gerar algo do tipo (`[0]=>  "Hena"`), porém precisamos do `Hena` como uma chave e não um valor, para isso usamos o [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-flip.php) e então isso ficará `["Hena"]=> 0`.

2. O [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-intersect-key.php) retorna todos os valores da array `$valoresProdutos` que possuem chaves iguais ao do `$produtosEscolhidos`, assim se for selecionado apenas "Hena" ficará `["Hena"]=> 20` e se selecionar "Hena" e "Simples" ficará `["Hena"]=> 20, ["Simples"]=> 15`, **lembrando que isto é case-sensitive**.
3. Por fim usamos o [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-sum.php) para somar os valores dos `$valoresEscolhidos`, assim somamos tudo que foi selecionado pelo usuário.
4. *O `echo` foi utilizado apenas para mostrar o resultado.*

---

Como disse é possível fazer isto sem a necessidade de usar essas funções, afinal talvez desconheça-los ou ache que seja complexo, acredito que o importante é entender como funciona (recomendo que leia a documentação) ao invés de dar um CTRL+C e CTRL+V. Enfim, podemos utilizar o `foreach` e verificar se o usuário selecionou ou não aquele item.

```
$valoresSomados = 0;

foreach($valoresProdutos as $_nomeProduto => $_valorProduto){

    if( isset($_POST[$_nomeProduto]) ){
        $valoresSomados += $_valorProduto;
    }

}

echo $valoresSomados;
```

[TESTE ISTO AQUI](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59ff40e299d956f950263fb869b34012eaa276c4)

Acredito que neste caso é auto-explicativo, você tem o `$valoresSomados` de inicialmente `0`, então ele pega a lista `$valoresProdutos` e verifica se o usuário selecionou (i.e. se existir `$_POST['Hena']` é porque o usuário selecionou), então somamos o preço da "Hena" ao `$valoresSomados`.

---

Você também poderia gerar o checkbox da seguinte maneira:

```
$valoresProdutos = [

    'Hena' => 20,
    'Simples' => 15,
    'MaquiagemIndividual' => 100

];

echo '<form action="sua_pagina.php" method="post">';

foreach($valoresProdutos as $_nomeProduto => $_valorProduto){

    echo '<label>';
    echo    '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$_nomeProduto.'" value="true">';
    echo    $_nomeProduto;
    echo '</label>';

    echo '<br>';
}

echo '<input type="submit" name="Enviar">';

echo '</form>';
```

Assim automaticamente quando adicionado um novo item na *array* iria existir num novo checkbox. Uma outra opção seria criar funções que criassem o HTML, [por exemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/794129b6ed3289ccf9232553b8b23e40e8e0be06).

Comment: Grande Inkeliz,  está dando erro: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in..... on line 3.  A linha 3 é $valoresProdutos = [

Comment: Qual sua versão do PHP? É menor que o PHP 5.4?! Se for terá que trocar para `array(` e depois `)`, ao invés de `[` e `]`. *Tente atualizar isto para uma versão mais recente, se possível, isto é muito antigo, o PHP 5.3 foi descontinuado em Agosto de 2014.*

Comment: Hummm, e se usar array( ...); em versões atuais vai funcionar?

Comment: eu coloquei isso $produtosEscolhidos = array_flip(array_keys($_POST)) e ele só traz assim [0] => 'hena' o jeito que vc falou é mto bom até economiza código porém nao consegui fazer :/

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo sim, o `array()` é compatível com todas as versões.

Comment: @heitor_deep, utilizar o `array_flip(array_keys($_POST))` você ainda precisa utilizar o resto do código, isto apenas irá fazer com que os valores  sejam removidos (por exemplo `hena=QualquerCoisa` fique `hena=0`), na prática não tem diferença entre os dois, apenas deixa claro que você está interessado nos indexes e não nos valores, se você no futuro ver o código, o `array_keys()` já vai apontar para você "isto pega as chaves", enquanto o `$_POST` você sabe que tem todo o conteúdo. O `$valoresSomados = array_sum(array_intersect_key($valoresProdutos, $_POST));` faz tudo. ;)

Comment: @Inkeliz - Meu pensamento: O ideal é uma resposta que atendesse todos da comunidade!!!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que da seguinte forma já simplificaria bastante:

```
$isHena = isset($hena); 
$isSimples = isset($simples); 
$isMaquiagem = isset($maquiagem);
$resultado = $isHena * $valorHena + $isSimples * $valorSimples + $isMaquiagem * $valorMaquiagem;
$dado->setResultado($resultado);
```

Porque o valor do `isset` vai retornar `true` ou `false`, que será `0` ou `1` na multiplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Galera consegui resolver meu problema segue o código a baixo

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['ok'])) {
      // checkbox ta assim name="servico[simples] servico[hena]...." no value ta o valor total.
$servicos = $_POST['servico'];
// Devino os valores aqui
$post = array(
    'servico' => array(
        0 => 15,
        1 => 20,
        2 => 100,
        3 => 30,
        )
);

if (!empty($servicos)){
    $variavel = "";
    foreach ($servicos as $campo => $valor) {
          // pego o nome (hena,simples, blábáblá)  
        $variavel .= $campo . ' ';      
        // soma de todos os checkbox que foi digitado
        $re = array_sum($servicos);

    }
    // apartir daqui jogo no setter e mando bala.
   echo $re . '<br/>';
   echo $variavel;


}else{
    echo "não foi passado";
}
}

?>
```